# Close Dropdown menu by clicking outside of it (Angular 4)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, drop-down-menu

So I have an input:

```
<input id='search'placeholder="Search" formControlName='search'
       (click)="toggleDropDown()" type='text' novalidate>
```

when you click on it, it shows a "dropdown" menu:

```
<div *ngIf="showDropDown"
           class="search-bar-results">
        <li
          *ngFor="let x of searchItems | filter: getSearchValue()"
          (click)="selectValue(artist)">
            <img src="{{x.image}}"
                 alt="search result artist image"
                 class="search-bar-image">
            <p>{{x.name}}</p>
            <p>{{x.type}}</p>
        </li>
      </div>
```

Here is the TypeScript:

```
showDropDown = false;

toggleDropDown() {
    this.showDropDown = !this.showDropDown;
    console.log('clicked');
  }
```

When a user clicks on the input, the dropdown appears in the DOM / on the screen. So far I can only close the dropdown by clicking on the input itself, but I am trying to find a way to close the menu by clicking elsewhere.

Comment: I see you are solely relying on the input box's click event. How about trying `(blur)`? https://angular.io/guide/user-input#on-blur

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Referring to `blur`: [Angular 2 on blur](https://angular.io/guide/user-input#on-blur)

Something in line with this:

```
<input id='search'placeholder="Search" formControlName='search'
   (click)="toggleDropDown()" (blur)="closeDropDown()" type='text' novalidate>
```

TS:

```
closeDropDown() {
    this.showDropDown = false;
    console.log('clicked outside');
}
```

Comment: thank you very much ! solved the problem directly and reminded me of blur haha

Comment: glad to hear it :)

Comment: Good answer. Straight and to the point. This will work in any version of the framework by the wait, so 2+. Generally we don't say angular2 anymore we just say angular because angularjs turned out not to be version 1.0 of angular 2+

Answer (score 1):

you can do the following:

1) add host in your "@Component" decorator:

```
  host: {
    "(window:click)": "onDropClick()"
  }
```

2) add function that you called on host:

```
  onDropClick() { // close drop down
    this.YOUR-DROP-DOWN-NAME = false;
  }
```

3) Stop propagation of your drop event:

```
  onSearchDrop(event) { // YOUR DROP DOWN FUNCTION
    event.stopPropagation(); // Drop down propagation
  }
```

example:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-search-page',
  templateUrl: './search-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search-page.component.scss'],

  host: {
    "(window:click)": "onDropClick()"
  }

})
export class SearchPageComponent implements OnInit {
  searchDrop = false;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onSearchDrop(event) {
    this.searchDrop = true;
    this.modalDrop = false;

    event.stopPropagation(); // Drop down propagation
  }


  onDropClick() { // close drop down
    this.searchDrop = false;
  }

}
```